# About Nonlinear System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I´ve never studied anything about systems of differential equations, but I´ve came across with two I´ve got to solve, which are nonlinear.

[image]

AND

[image]

---

I´ve been looking on internet and I´ve foudn this method for linear SD:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vB3fx5BImU

But my question is, if there is a numerical method or something with which i can "solve" this systems.

Comment: Runge-Kutta-4, http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Course_Notes/Differential_Equations_Notes/node5.html or use Mahtematica, Python, Maple V, Matlab, SAGE...

Comment: You might even be able to eliminate some of the equations.

Comment: The first is the system for the chaotic Lorenz attractor with different parameters than the ones used for the iconic pictures. What are the tools (as enumerated by Moo) that you intend to use? What do you understand as "numerical solution"? Usually it is a function table or a piecewise polynomial approximation of the solution.